# Changing Origin Id & Battlefield

Tags: battlefield-4, origin

If you change your origin ID, does your battlefield profile, level, guns, etc. remain intact?

Comment: Yup, origin support can also (provided you light a fire under their a--es) transfer games/accolades to another account. I had to do this when my account was stolen and I had to recover it to a new email. I don't recommend this as its extremely time consuming and frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does, you can change your name as much as you like (although there is a waiting period) but your games and their accounts will not be affected.

This is because games are linked to your account ID not your Name